# Is there a way to optimise a statsmodels funtion to polars

Tags: python-polars

I am transcribing a script from pandas to polars. At one point I run this function

`from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose`

`decompose_result = seasonal_decompose(ts, model="additive")`

What would be the most efficient way of doing this with polars?

Should I transform my polars df to a pandas df for this function?
Is there a way of defining a UDF?

Answer (score 1):

If you have...

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':np.random.uniform(1,100,745)}) \
     .with_columns(ts=pl.date_range(pl.datetime(2023,1,1), pl.datetime(2023,2,1),'1h', eager=False))
```

then you can do

```
df.with_columns(atrend=pl.col('a').map(lambda x: pl.Series(seasonal_decompose(x, period=24).trend)))
```

There's some slight issue with not using a pandas df in that you then have to specify the period parameter. When you use pandas and the default period then this is what happens...

The source of `seasonal_decompose` has this section:

```
if period is None:
    pfreq = getattr(getattr(x, "index", None), "inferred_freq", None)
```

and

```
if period is None:
    if pfreq is not None:
        pfreq = freq_to_period(pfreq)
```

then if you look at what `freq_to_period` does, it's just this...

```
if freq == 'A' or freq.startswith(('A-', 'AS-')):
    return 1
elif freq == 'Q' or freq.startswith(('Q-', 'QS-')):
    return 4
elif freq == 'M' or freq.startswith(('M-', 'MS')):
    return 12
elif freq == 'B' or freq == 'W' or freq.startswith('W-'):
    return 52
```

I would think you would just know if you have annual, quarterly, monthly, or weekly data so it shouldn't really be too tough to fill in the period with 1, 4, 12, or 52 to get the same effect.

if you want the actual resultant object rather than just adding the trend column into a `with_columns` contenxt then you can do

```
decompose_result = seasonal_decompose(df.get_column('ts'), model="additive", period=24)
```

If you want to "bolt-on" seasonal_decompose to pl and DataFrames then you can follow [this](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.api.register_dataframe_namespace.html)

like this

```
@pl.api.register_dataframe_namespace("sm")
class sm:
    from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose 
    def __init__(self, df: pl.DataFrame):
        self._df = df

    def seasonal_decompose(self, x, model='additive', filt=None, period=None, two_sided=True, extrapolate_trend=0):
        return seasonal_decompose(self._df.get_column(x), model=model, filt=filt, period=period, two_sided=two_sided, extrapolate_trend=extrapolate_trend)
```

which then allows you to do:

```
df.sm.seasonal_decompose('a', period=24)
```

Answer (score 0):

See functions like [`apply`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.apply.html#polars.DataFrame.apply) and [`pipe`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pipe.html#polars.DataFrame.pipe) for UDFs. It seems you're feeding a DF in, so probably `pipe` here:

`decompose_result = ts.pipe(seasonal_decompose, model="additive")`

If your UDF doesn't play nice with a polars DF and you have to have that function, you might have to resort to conversions.